# Can I use two widgets for the same key?

Tags: flutter, email, dart, passwords, key

I'm trying to see the password and the user email in the terminal when I touch the button but it gives me some errors.

- I tried with two keys but it gives me errors
- I tried to put a body: form above my widget but I don't have a scaffold one so it doesn't work plus I tried to change to scaffold but it's worse and I have no more backgrounds.

So there would be a way to show the password and email with a kind of _formKey1 and _formKey2 system which allows many keys ?
**I think the problem is coming from my globalkey**

This is some of my code

```
class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  final _formKey =new GlobalKey<FormState>();

  late String _email;
  late String _password;
```

and

```
@override
  Widget build (BuildContext context) {
    return Background(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("SIGNUP", style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 20),
            ),
            Container(child: Image.asset('assets/ctlogo.png', height: 200),
            ),
            RoundedInputField(
              key: _formKey,
                hintText: "Your Email",
                onChanged:(value) => setState(() => _email = value),
            ),
            RoundedPasswordField(
              key: _formKey,
              onChanged: (value) => setState(() => _password = value),
            ),
            Container(margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
              width: 300,
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(29),
                // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                child: FlatButton(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14, horizontal: 40),
                  color: DarkTurquoise,
                  onPressed: (){print(_email); print(_password);
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
```

with the errors "*too many widget for the same keys*" and "*LateInitializationError: Field '_password@30293343' has not been initialized*"

and my rounded_password_field code

```
class RoundedPasswordField extends StatefulWidget {

  final ValueChanged<String> onChanged;
  const RoundedPasswordField({
    required this.onChanged,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RoundedPasswordFieldState createState() => _RoundedPasswordFieldState();
}
class _RoundedPasswordFieldState extends State<RoundedPasswordField> {
  bool _isSecret = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFieldContainer(
      child: TextField(
        obscureText: _isSecret,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: "Password",
          border: InputBorder.none,
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.lock,
            color: DarkTurquoise,
          ),
          suffixIcon: InkWell(
            onTap: () =>
                setState(() => _isSecret = !_isSecret),
            child: Icon(!_isSecret
                ? Icons.visibility
                : Icons.visibility_off, color: DarkTurquoise),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, two widgets can't share a `GlobalKey`. Furthermore, your `GlobalKey` should only be used in a `Form` widget since it holds a `FormState`.

In this case, you probably don't need to use a `GlobalKey`, since you are not using it. Instead, try removing the key and then test your code again.

Also, only use [`late` fields](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#late-variables) if you are sure they will be initialized properly. In this case, try replacing them with:

```
String _email = '';
String _password = '';
```

Comment: Thank you it's working, is it  normal that I don't see the password field ?

Comment: What do you mean? Is the text being obscured by the dots, or the whole field does not appear? Try looking into the `RoundedPasswordField` implementation.

Comment: In the terminal running app I have this                                                                   
I/flutter ( 3141): ajidj@gmail.com
I/flutter ( 3141):                               (like you can see there is nothing after that whereas it's supposed to contain the password

Comment: Are you sure the `RoundedPasswordField` widget is calling the `onChanged` function?

Comment: I updated my post with the RoundedPasswordField code and I tried to put  `onChanged: onChanged,` but with not success

Comment: The `RoundedPasswordField` seems incomplete, can you post a full version? Or paste it somewhere like gist.github.com

Comment: Thank you the problem was from there, I just put a `onChanged: widget.onChanged;` and it was ok